# How do I .Incluce() only the last element of an ICollection in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a db model like this

```
    public partial class ChatThread : BaseEntity
    {
        [ForeignKey("ChatThreadID")]
        public ICollection<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to return only the latest element added to the ChatMessages relationship

I have tried the following in my get request but it didn't work

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ChatThread>>> GetThreads()
        {
            var threads = _context.ChatThreads.Where(thread => thread.User1 == UserId || thread.User2 == UserId).Include(t => t.ChatMessages.Last());
            return await threads.ToListAsync();
        }
```

is there a way of using something like `.Include(t => t.ChatMessages.Last());` to just return one item instead of every single chat message in that thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Projection is suited to view concerns. You can create a view model for the Chat Thread and Chat Message, either flattening the details or as separate models.

For instance with a flattened view model:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChatThreadViewModel
{
    public int ChatThreadId { get; set; }
    // Other chat thread fields needed for view...

    public int LatestChatMessageId { get; set; }
    public string LatestChatMessage { get; set; }
    // any other chat message fields needed for view...
}
```

Then when reading...

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ChatThreadViewModel>>> GetThreads()
{
    var threadDetails = await _context.ChatThreads
        .Where(thread => thread.User1 == UserId 
            || thread.User2 == UserId)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            x.ChatThreadId,
            LastChatMessage = x.ChatMessages
               .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.ChatMessageDateTime)
               .Select(cm => new 
               {
                   cm.ChatMessageId,
                   cm.Message
               }).First()
        }).ToListAsync();

    return await threadDetails
        .Select(x => new ChatThreadViewModel
        {
            ChatThreadId = x.ChatThreadId,
            LastChatMessageId = x.LastChatMessage.ChatMessageId,
            LastChatMessage = x.LastChatMessage.Message
        }).ToListAsync();
}
```

To flatten the details we do a double-projection, where the first query just pulls the relational details we want, then the second query does the flattening. This simplifies the SQL being generated rather than doing something like:

```
        .Select(x => new ChatThreadViewModel
        {
            ChatThreadId = x.ChatThreadId,
            LastChatMessageId = x.ChatMessages
               .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.ChatMessageDateTime)
               .Select(cm => cm.ChatMessageId)
               .First(),
            LastChatMessage = x.ChatMessages
               .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.ChatMessageDateTime)
               .Select(cm => cm.Message)
               .First()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Which would create a `JOIN` on ChatMessages for each field we wanted to pull back.

Alternatively if you want a ChatThreadViewModel containing a ChatMessageViewModel for the "LatestMessage" then you can populate those in a single projection.  This option would work best with Automapper.

The alternative option would be to populate a detached ChatThread entity in the query where we only load a single ChatMessage for the latest message. Something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ChatThread>>> GetThreads()
{
    var threads = await _context.ChatThreads
        .Where(thread => thread.User1 == UserId 
            || thread.User2 == UserId)
        .Select(x => new ChatThread
        {
            ChatThreadId = x.ChatThreadId,
            // Populate all other fields in the chat thread...

            ChatMessages = x.ChatMessages
               .OrderByDescending(cm => cm.ChatMessageDateTime)
               .Select(cm => new ChatMessage
               {
                   ChatMessageId = cm.ChatMessageId,
                   Message = cm.Message,
                   // Populate all other fields from the chat message...
               }).Take(1)
               .ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();

    return threads;
}
```

The caveat of using an approach like this is that the Entity no longer represents a complete representation of the data state. This can be easily confused when creating methods that accept things like ChatThread entities as something created like this is neither a complete representation of that original ChatThread, nor is it a "complete-able" one. (I.e. a lazy-loadable instance that could load ChatMessages or other related entities if needed) It cannot be safely attached and used as a representation of a whole ChatThread so there is an ongoing risk that code could be called with one of these incomplete  data representations masked as an entity.